# Does Dark Energy contribute to increase the isothermal temperature of plasma in galaxy clusters?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, space-expansion, galaxies, dark-energy

I have a question about this work called "[Dark energy and key physical parameters of clusters of galaxies](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.1433)"

There, towards the end, the authors talk about the isothermal velocities and temperature parameters of the gas and particles circulating between galaxies in clusters. In particular they calculate the isothermal plasma temperature (equation 37):
$$
T_{iso} = \frac{Gm}{3k}V^2_{iso}=\frac{m}{3k}(\frac{8\pi}{3}\rho_\Lambda)^\frac{1}{3}M^\frac{2}{3}
$$

I can note there is a contribution from a dark energy parameter in that equation (the cube root of the dark energy density value is present in the equation, represented by ρΛ, which should give a large number as the dark energy density in space is small). I tried to ask the authors themselves, but they only told me that "*Temperature is defined from virial relation. It contains Dark Energy due to its antigravity*"

Does it mean that dark energy contributes to the value of that temperature? Does dark energy help to increase the value of that temperature? And if it does, how?